# How do you get a list of files included in a diff?

Tags: diff, patch

I have a patch file containing the output from `git diff`. I want to get a summary of all the files that, according to the patch file, have been added or modified. What command can I use to achieve this?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`patchutils` includes a `lsdiff` utility.

Comment: Too bad it isn't part of the standard patch or diff package.

Answer (score 3):

`grep '+++' mydiff.patch` seems to do the trick.

I can also use `git diff --names-only` which is probably the better approach.

Comment: Renamed files are skipped when using grep '+++'

Comment: `grep '^+++ ' mydiff.patch` would be better if your patch file includes patch files

Answer (score 3):

```
grep '+++' mydiff.patch|perl -pe 's/\+\+\+ //g'
```

Details:

git diff produces output in the format

```
+++ b/file
```

So if you're using grep as Nathan suggested

```
grep '+++' mydiff.patch
```

You'll have the list of affected files, prepended by '+++ ' (3 plus signs and a space).

I often need to further process files and find it convenient to have one filename per line without anything else. This can be achieved with the following command, where perl/regex removes these plus signs and the space.

```
grep '+++' mydiff.patch|perl -pe 's/\+\+\+ //g'
```

For patch files generated with diff -Naur, the mydiff.patch file contains entries with filename and date ( is indicating the tabulator whitespace character)

```
+++ b/file<tab>2013-07-03 13:58:45.000000000 +0200
```

To extract the filenames for this, use

```
grep '+++' mydiff.patch|perl -pe 's/\+\+\+ (.*)\t.*/\1/g'
```

Answer (score 2):

A decent way to do this is to use the --stat flag (or the --summary flag, if you need only new / deleted / renamed files for some reason).

Example:

```
git apply --stat peer.diff | awk '{ print $1 }' | sed '$d'
1-js/03-code-quality/index.md
CONTR.md
LICENSE.md
README.md
chat-app.readme.md
```

Comment: Nice trick, but unreliable for biggers paths as they get stripped

Answer (score 0):

When you parse patches generated by `git format-patch` or others containing additional information about number of lines edited, it's crucial to search for `^+++` (at the start of the line) rather than just `+++`.

For example:

`grep '^+++' *.patch  | sed -e 's#+++ [ab]/##'`

will output paths without `a/` or `b/` at the begin.